# Parameter cannot be executed in the JSF ajax tag

Tags: java, ajax, jsf

The '1' in the cc.attrs.controllerBean.goToPage('1') cannot be executed. However, if i do it without the forEach loop, the 1 can get executed just fine. Any idea why?

```
<c:forEach begin="1" step="1" end="#{cc.attrs.controllerBean.noOfPages}" varStatus="status">
        <li><h:commandLink value="#{status.index}">
            <f:ajax execute="@form" render="searchResult" action="#{cc.attrs.controllerBean.goToPage('1')}" />
        </h:commandLink></li>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have an old version of jstl installed in your webapp?

Comment: @SteveC i'm using 1.2

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, you should avoid JSTL in JSF View definitions. You can do the same thing using the `<ui:repeat />` tag, just define in your backing bean a list of integers that holds the number of pages:

```
<!-- pages is a list of integers that holds the number of pages -->
<ui:repeat value="#{cc.attrs.controllerBean.pages}" var="pageNumber">       
    <h:commandLink value="#{pageNumber}">
          <!-- rest of your code -->
    </h:commandLink>
</ui:repeat>
```

Also remember that `<f:ajax />` supports the listener attribute, not the action.